# Is installing packages with apt-get faster than apt?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Is installing packages with `apt-get` faster than `apt`?

Answer (score 4):

Installing packages with apt-get is not faster than apt. apt and apt-get both download from the same update server (whatever update server mirror you selected) at the same download speed.

From the accepted answer to [What is the difference between apt and apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/q/445384/):

> `apt-get` may be considered as lower level and "back-end", and supports other apt-based software tools. `apt` is designed for end users and its output may be changed between versions.

Answer (score 1):

No, `apt` is an interface for `apt-get`. **They both have the same speed**. `apt` is not CLI stable. Speed depends on the Download server. Look [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1378188/1460940) for more detail. If you want a better speed you can use [`apt-fast`](https://askubuntu.com/a/501905/1460940).

This [website](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/apt-vs-apt-get#:%7E:text=the%20apt%20command-,1.,GET%20and%20APT%2DCACHE%20Functionalities&text=With%20the%20release%20of%20Ubuntu,under%20the%20same%20command%20prefix) may help.

> Before Ubuntu 16.04, users regularly interacted with the APT package manager through the use of command-line tools: apt-get, apt-cache, and apt-config. Although these tools offer many functionalities, most average users did not utilize all of the commands they provide.
>
> Therefore, Linux wanted to create a simplified tool that only consisted of essential commands. With the release of Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 8, they introduced a new command-line interface – apt.
>
> The main goal for this novelty was to merge the most commonly used apt-get and apt-cache commands under the same command prefix.